# Passing boundary conditions to solver

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, linear-solver, poisson

Quite broad question,
Currently building own Poisson solver subroutine for CFD solver.

Works smooth, the goal is to generalise the input and make it flexible.

Description of also:

1. Memory allocation.
2. Filling source right hand side $-\Delta u(x,y) = f(x,y)$ function of Poisson equation.
3. Filling sparse matrix with inner nodes with coefficients of discretisation (1/dx2, 2/dx2, 1dy2, 2/dy2)
4. Entering into matrix BC's (here I do hardcoding - L R T B separately and corners).
5. Converting to Sparse CSR format.
6. Calling Conjugate Gradient solver function.
7. Writing output to a file.
8. Ending, freeing memory.

If I figure our how to generalise input will likely get rid of the step 5 and input directly into the dense matrix of CSR format. Because initially I used two matrices

```
matrixOfValues 
matrixOfLocations
```

Both are matrices of size $(N_x N_y)\cdot 5$ of int/double (location/value),
5 is for the node with 4 neighbours in x and y directions.

The purpose of the intermediate storage was to not mess up, however most of the time is consumed by ConjGrad solver anyway.

Any recommendations on passing the BC's to the solver more generally without hardcoding?
On top of that, there are three different types of BC, namely: Dirichlet, Neumann and Robin.

Feels like throwing math function as an argument is not a good idea, I could pass an array (say Western wall nodes as a start, then move counterclockwise, and passing all of the boundary node coefficients, i.e. a triangle with neighbours and, perhaps, separate for corners), but why need to invent the bicycle if this should've been done earlier in the most effective way.

Any relevant literature you can recommend?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want to write your own solver from scratch? Real software uses many thousands, probably tens of thousands of lines of code to do these steps. It seems silly to reinvent the wheel when you could just take what others have already done and focus on what is actually *new* and *interesting* in your work!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth because I’m bad at coding and want to improve skills while doing something meaningful that I actually like :)

Comment: What language are you using?  Also I am not entirely sure why passing a function as an argument is a bad idea.

Comment: @KyleMandli using C